# How do I open an url in a new tab via php?

Tags: php, url, browser

```
<a href="Link" target="_blank">Go!</a>
```

like this code but using php thanks

Comment: echo '<a href="Link" target="_blank">Go!</a>';

Comment: PHP is a server-side scripting language. What you have provided here is HTML.

Only servers interpret PHP code.
@bestprogrammerintheworld's code will print the HTML, and send it to the client(browser), where a click will open a new window with that URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change location with php:

```
header("location:somewhere.php");
```

but in the same tab - php will not tell the browser to open it in new tab. This must be done by javascript after reloading by the header function, but you will not know if it will open in new tab or in new window anyway - it is up to the browser settings!

Remember that you cannot output even single character to the browser (no echo, no html tags) before calling header function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure that's what you want it, but it is what I understood.

```
<?php

echo '<a href="Link" target="_blank">Go!</a>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you know you can name a file .php and still have php and html code on it? you just have to put  at the start and end of the code and then just write rest on html outside of those code brackets.